# how to connect Samsung Galaxy gear of sdk 17

Tags: android, wear-os

I have Samsung galaxy gear watch and its Sdk is 17 , and What Watch face I have developed its minimum sdk is 20 , So I can not test my app on direct usb debuging of Samsung Galaxy gear.

and If I try to to change the minimum sdk , androd studio gives error of manifest merger error ?

what should I do ?? Any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to have SDK 21 (Android Wear v5.0.1) at least on your watch to use the Watch Face API, as said in the documentation. So I suggest you update your watch to Android Wear 5.0.1 and set your target SDK and min SDK to 21.

Comment: I have Samsung Galaxy gear watch , How to update it to 4.4 or as you said v5.0.1 but not to update it to tizen

Comment: Don't you have an update option under the "about" in the parameters ?

Comment: no I dont have . And when I want to do update using kies , it takes me to tizen which I dont want to do. So Can I get the higher version in android

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have Galaxy Gear - not Galaxy Gear Live. So your watch doesn't run on Android Wear - thus you cannot use WatchFace API or update it to latest version of Android Wear.

Comment: yes As i described above I have Galaxy Gear not Galaxy gear live , and its on android 4.2<sdk17> but I want android 4.4 <sdk 20> so if I go for updates, it asks me to directly update on tizen not to any other higher android version. So in this case what should I do ?

Comment: There is no update for later Android version for that watch. They replace it with Tizen and Android is no longer supported on it.

Comment: So Can you please make  it clear to me that if I update it to tizen , would it be able to run the Android app on it ??? as Tizen is open source

Comment: No it wont. Tizen apps are different from Android ones.